# Calling MySQL stored procedure / query from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Is there any way to call a MySQL stored procedure / query from a SQL Server stored procedure?

Regards,
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine)

Then you call it like this in your procedure

```
EXEC('MySQL_Procedure;') AT MySQLSERVER;
```

Or using [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql) / [OPENQUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql)

Comment: Can you please explain how to link my both servers as both are at different hosting place . Though Both hosting under my control